# Set \labeldist for 1 message

Tags: pstricks, msc

I'm drawing a message exchange sequence with the `msc` package, and I have some problems with the `\labeldist` on the messages.

Here is the MWE :

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table, usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks, pst-node, pst-circ, pst-plot, pst-3dplot, pst-solides3d, pst-sigsys, pstricks-add, pst-eucl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[locale=FR, per-mode=symbol, abbreviations]{siunitx}
\usepackage{msc}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand\msckeyword{}
\setlength{\instdist}{7cm} 
\setlength{\instwidth}{4cm}
\setlength{\envinstdist}{4.5cm}
%\setlength{\labeldist}{0.05cm}

\begin{msc}{}
    \declinst{client}{}{\textbf{Client}}
    \declinst{serveur}{}{\textbf{Server}}
        \mess{\rotatebox{-8}{small info}}{client}[.3]{serveur}[2]
        \action*{\textcolor{WildStrawberry}{Action !}}{serveur}
    \nextlevel[3]
        \mess{\rotatebox{4}{longer info to put here}}{serveur}[.3]{client}[1]
    \nextlevel[2]
\end{msc}

\end{document}
```

And it produces this :

[image: MWE result]

With the rotation of the label, the distances between the label and the arrow are bigger on the second message, and I can't solve it.

I've seen in the [documentation](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/msc/refman.pdf) that it's possible to adjust the `\labeldist` parameter, but I can't do it **locally**.

Has anybody an idea how to do it ? It should be really simple, but I can't find the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
    \mess{\rotatebox[origin=r]{4}{longer info to put here}}{serveur}[.3]{client}[1]
```

Comment: Thanks ! And any ideas to delete the frame around the picture ?

Comment: write into the preamble after loading `msc`: `\drawframe{no}`

Comment: I `\include` this drawing into my main.tex, and as I add pstricks lines on it, they don't appear at the same place on the main pdf. Have you any tracks ? Posting a MWE could be very long...

Comment: I never used `msc`. So I have no idea how `msc` defines the coordinates. However you can use `\rput(0,0){the msc image}` or any other coordinates.

Comment: Ah okay. But it's said in the doc that we can include PSTricks code within the `\begin{msc}`. When I compile the standalone it's OK, but not if I compile the `main.tex`... Maybe it's because of the width superior than the `pagewidth`...

Answer (score 1):

You can set `\labeldist` just before the command in question:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{msc,graphicx,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\msckeyword{}
\setlength{\instdist}{7cm} 
\setlength{\instwidth}{4cm}
\setlength{\envinstdist}{4.5cm}

\begin{msc}{}
  \declinst{client}{}{\textbf{Client}}
  \declinst{serveur}{}{\textbf{Server}}
    \mess{\rotatebox{-8}{small info}}{client}[.3]{serveur}[2]
    \action*{\textcolor{red!80}{Action !}}{serveur}
  \nextlevel[3]
    \setlength{\labeldist}{-.5mm}
    \mess{\rotatebox{4}{longer info to put here}}{serveur}[.3]{client}[1]
  \nextlevel[2]
\end{msc}

\end{document}
```

One could also create this drawing using [`pstricks](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) alone.

Comment: Thanks, but herbert's solution seem less tricky for me, although it isn't a direct `msc` option.